# What is the SQL Server least privilege for AppFabric installation?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, appfabric

We are trying to develop a repeatable process for installing **AppFabric**, using a **SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition** instance.

I granted the SQL Server login (using Windows Authentication) being used to install AppFabric the `db_creator` Server Role, since AppFabric clearly needs to create databases. During Installation of AppFabric, they receive the error:

> "The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_add_category',
>   database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. Could not find stored procedure
>   'ASInternal_ThrowError'.

I can't very well grant `EXECUTE` to a stored procedure in a database that doesn't exist when I am granting Server Roles to the login. I have been unable to find any documentation regarding the minimum SQL Server permissions required for the AppFabric installation.

I suppose I could just grant the sysadmin Server Role to that user account, but I'd rather not.

Comment: grant sysadmin role for the installed then remove it.

Comment: You should have the msdb database.  It's a System database that manages jobs, scheduling, etc.  Not sure why permissions are an issue though.

Comment: Is the guest user disabled in the msdb database?

Comment: The User "guest" is not disabled in msdb.